# Store the Password to other field for Partner users?

Tags: apex, community

I am working on communities. My requirement is on a VF page when a user enters username and clicks on 'Change Password' button, the controller needs to store the original password of that user to another field for future reference. Can this be achieved with Salesforce?
 Any inputs will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible but keep it in a encrypted field.
You can use your custom controller on login attempts. Check out 
"Site.Login(username,password)".
But it brings another requirement , you should handle change password action as well.